# App crashes when testing on iPhone X, but simulator it works fine, what is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an app that I have been testing with simulator and my iPhone interchangeable.  I made some changes and was testing with the simulator and received no errors.  When I switched back to the iPhone it crashed attempting to segue with the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x290)"  I included the chunk of code where the crash happens and comments around the line of failure. I am stumped because googling that error goes down a serious rabit hole and frankly I don't see why it would work on the simulator but not the phone.  Any help to try and diagnose the cause of this would be greatly appreciated.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showImageSubmit"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! ImageSubmit
        vc.newImage = newImage
        vc.newImageCreateDate = imageCreationDate
    } else if segue.identifier == "showSlideShow"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! SlideShow
        // This is where it fails
        vc.mode = segueMode
        vc.userProfile = userProfile
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the simulator was ok with executing fuctions for UIButton that didn't have @objc as the start but phone was not.   The app has a UIButton custom class to control formatting of filter buttons and when I switched all functions to have @objc in front of them iphone resumed working like simulator.  Very odd the 2 behaved differently, but hopefully someone else will find this and have something to check.